# How to pass multiple queries in to a procedure as input

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I am having a requirement in which i need to pass 6 sql statements to a procedure and it should return the
output of those 6 statements

I have written as below but it is only working for one sql statement as input

```
Begin set @c = inputSql;  
prepare stmt from @c; 
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
end
```

Comment: Dynamic sql can only execute 1 statement at a time..so if inputsql contains 6 statements only first will be executed.

Comment: So how can I do this is there any solution

Comment: split inputsql and submit 1 at a time or pass 6 separate statements and execute them one at a time. But I'm not seeing why you would want to do this and you haven't said..

Comment: Please add 6 sql statements (inputsql) you want to execute and their expected results in your question.